# is it possible to retrieve CWindow's timer information?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

im looking for a way to retrieve the timeout value set by the developer using the `SetTimer` function.

this is because different appraches should be taken according to its value.

thanks!

Comment: In what context? Surely you set the timer and know how long you set it to? You then normally use the timer ID to determine which timer it is and what it should be doing.

Comment: Unlikely. If you don't need to respond to set timer immediately, you can use `Spy++` SDK tool to watch messages and see when the `WM_TIMER` messages arrives and hence the timeout set in first place.